# Open text file not in current folder in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to open a text file using uigetfile but it gives me an error when I open a text file other from the current folder. Is there a way to fix this?

I wrote:

```
FileName = uigetfile('*.txt', 'Open text file');
file = load(FileName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the complete path:

```
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.txt', 'Open text file');
file = load(fullfile(PathName,FileName));
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. Is there a way of opening multiple files at once using uigetfile and saving it into a variable?

Comment: Yes, if you set `MultiSelect` to `on`, it will return a cell array of filenames and then you have loop through them to load them one at a time. Check the  [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uigetfile.html) for the correct syntax. If you select multiple files, they must all be in the same folder.